# How to integrate the pay u money integration by using webview?

Tags: java, android, payumoney

I am fresher to android app development, i am facing the issue in integrating the pay u money integration by using web view in android. I am using the minimum sdk version 15. The code for integrating the pay u money is attached below

```
   public class PayUMoneyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * Adding WebView as setContentView
     */
    WebView webView;

    /**
     * Context for Activity
     */
    Context activity;
    /**
     * Order Id
     * To Request for Updating Payment Status if Payment Successfully Done
     */
    int mId; //Getting from Previous Activity
    /**
     * Required Fields
     */
    // Test Variables
    /*
    private String mMerchantKey = "FCyqqZ";
    private String mSalt = "sfBpGA8E";
    private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";
    */

    // Final Variables
    private String mMerchantKey = "JBZaLc";
    private String mSalt = "GQs7yium";
    private String mBaseURL = "https://test.payu.in";


    private String mAction = ""; // For Final URL
    private String mTXNId; // This will create below randomly
    private String mHash; // This will create below randomly
    private String mProductInfo = "Food Items"; //Passing String only
    private String mFirstName; // From Previous Activity
    private String mEmailId; // From Previous Activity
    private double mAmount; // From Previous Activity
    private String mPhone; // From Previous Activity
    private String mServiceProvider = "payu_paisa";
    private String mSuccessUrl = "your success URL";
    private String mFailedUrl = "Your Failure URL";


    boolean isFromOrder;
    /**
     * Handler
     */
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /**
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */


    @SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /**
         * Setting WebView to Screen
         */

        /**
         * Creating WebView
         */
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payumoney_webview);

        /**
         * Context Variable
         */
        activity = getApplicationContext();


        /**
         * Getting Intent Variables...
         */
//        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
//        if (bundle != null) {

            mFirstName ="Kumar";
            mEmailId ="kumar@gmail.com";
            mAmount =30.0;
            mPhone ="123544567890";
            mId =12345;
            isFromOrder = true;

            Log.i("PaymentActivity", "" + mFirstName + " : " + mEmailId + " : " + mAmount + " : " + mPhone);

            /**
             * Creating Transaction Id
             */
            Random rand = new Random();
            String randomString = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt()) + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
            mTXNId = hashCal("SHA-256", randomString).substring(0, 20);

            mAmount = new BigDecimal(mAmount).setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP).intValue();

            /**
             * Creating Hash Key
             */
            mHash = hashCal("SHA-512", mMerchantKey + "|" +
                    mTXNId + "|" +
                    mAmount + "|" +
                    mProductInfo + "|" +
                    mFirstName + "|" +
                    mEmailId + "|||||||||||" +
                    mSalt);

            /**
             * Final Action URL...
             */
            mAction = mBaseURL.concat("/_payment");

            /**
             * WebView Client
             */
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "SSL Error! " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    handler.proceed();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                    if (url.equals(mSuccessUrl)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status", true);
                        intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                        intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (url.equals(mFailedUrl)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, PaymentStatusActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status", false);
                        intent.putExtra("transaction_id", mTXNId);
                        intent.putExtra("id", mId);
                        intent.putExtra("isFromOrder", isFromOrder);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
            });

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
            webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webView.clearHistory();
            webView.clearCache(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
            webView.addJavascriptInterface(new PayUJavaScriptInterface(PayUMoneyActivity.this), "PayUMoney");

            /**
             * Mapping Compulsory Key Value Pairs
             */
            Map<String, String> mapParams = new HashMap<>();

            mapParams.put("key", mMerchantKey);
            mapParams.put("txnid", mTXNId);
            mapParams.put("amount", String.valueOf(mAmount));
            mapParams.put("productinfo", mProductInfo);
            mapParams.put("firstname", mFirstName);
            mapParams.put("email", mEmailId);
            mapParams.put("phone", mPhone);
            mapParams.put("surl", mSuccessUrl);
            mapParams.put("furl", mFailedUrl);
            mapParams.put("hash", mHash);
            mapParams.put("service_provider", mServiceProvider);

            webViewClientPost(webView, mAction, mapParams.entrySet());
//        } else {
//            Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong, Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        }
    }

    /**
     * Posting Data on PayUMoney Site with Form
     *
     * @param webView
     * @param url
     * @param postData
     */
    public void webViewClientPost(WebView webView, String url,Collection<Map.Entry<String, String>> postData) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("<html><head></head>");
        sb.append("<body onload='form1.submit()'>");
        sb.append(String.format("<form id='form1' action='%s' method='%s'>", url, "post"));

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : postData) {
            sb.append(String.format("<input name='%s' type='hidden' value='%s' />", item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
        }
        sb.append("</form></body></html>");

        Log.d("TAG", "webViewClientPost called: " + sb.toString());
        webView.loadData(sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

    /**
     * Hash Key Calculation
     *
     * @param type
     * @param str
     * @return
     */
    public String hashCal(String type, String str) {
        byte[] hashSequence = str.getBytes();
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(type);
            algorithm.reset();
            algorithm.update(hashSequence);
            byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();

            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1)
                    hexString.append("0");
                hexString.append(hex);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException NSAE) {
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onPressingBack();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onPressingBack();
    }

    /**
     * On Pressing Back
     * Giving Alert...
     */
    private void onPressingBack() {

        final Intent intent;

//        if(isFromOrder)
//            intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, ProductInCartList.class);
//        else
//            intent = new Intent(PayUMoneyActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//
//        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(PayUMoneyActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you cancel this transaction?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();

            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public class PayUJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /**
         * Instantiate the interface and set the context
         */
        PayUJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void success(long id, final String paymentId) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    mHandler = null;
                    Toast.makeText(PayUMoneyActivity.this, "Payment Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error in my code but pay u money integration page is not viewing .

The error occurred  in web view is as below image.

[image]

Please help me how to solve this .

Comment: you should not expose your id and password like this.

Comment: @ Vivek Mishra  That is duplicate id found in some sample example program.